# Preferred way to use function outside document ready?

Tags: jquery

I know that I can define my function outside document ready handler and then call it like this:

```
function sayHello(){
  alert('hello');
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
    sayHello();       
  });
```

But I am not sure if there is a ***downside*** for doing it that way?

I also know that I can define my function using namespaces like so:

```
sayHi = {
  sayHello: function() {
      alert('hello');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function(){

sayHi.sayHello();    

});
```

So is my second example **better** then the *first one* or maybe there is even better solution for doing this?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve? Why do you *need* the function to be outside of the `document.ready`? In the first case, the downside is that it's global and can be accessed or overwritten by other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several recommendations in this regard:

1. **Define a function in the smallest scope possible.**  So, if `sayHi()` is only used inside of `document.ready()`, then define it inside of `document.ready()`.
2. **Create as few new global variables as possible.**  If you must define multiple things in the global scope, then it is generally a good idea to create a single global namespace object and put your other global things on it as properties.
3. **Use IIFE Closures to Wrap Code that Needs to Share.**  You can share functions among large pieces of code by wrapping the code in an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) without creating any globals.  This essentially creates a new function scope for a large piece of your code (or even all your code) and then you can define your common functions inside that scope.  Most of the jQuery library is inside one of these closures.  This also protects pieces of your code form unwanted outside access.
4. **Always use `var` (or also `let` in ES6) to explicitly declare your variables.**  This is so you never create accidental global or implicit global variables.
5. **Run in strict mode.** When running in strict mode, forgetting to use `var` or `let` will trigger an error that you will immediately see because implicit or accidental globals are errors in strict mode.

In your specific example, if you need to also call `sayHi()` from outside of `document.ready()`, then you can use an IIFE to avoid creating any new globals:

---

```
(function() {
    function sayHi() {
        alert('hello');
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        sayHi();
    });

    // other code
    // ...

    sayHi();

})();
```

---

If you don't need to call `sayHi()` from outside of `document.ready()`, then just define it inside of `document.ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function sayHi() {
        alert('hello');
    }

    sayHi();
});
```